# Was bedeutet "thun"?

Tags: meaning

Ich sehe immer die Wörter  **thun** und  **That**  und ich weiß nicht was sie bedeuten.

Was bedeuten die Wörter und warum existieren sie nicht in Wörterbüchern?

Comment: "thun" always reminds me of the following pun: "- Was wollen wir *thun-fisch*? - Du hast die *wahl-fisch*" :)

Comment: Wo siehst du diese Wörter? Kannst du einen Beispielsatz nennen?

Comment: Was heißt "immer"? Was liest du gerade? Karl May in Originalausgabe? Die Aufschriften auf Thunfischdosen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*That* und *thun* sind alte Schreibweisen von [*Tat*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Tat) und [*tun*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/tun). Man findet sie bis etwa Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts.

Mit der Standardisierung der deutschen Rechtschreibung im Jahre 1901 verschwand das *h* bei diesen und anderen Wörtern. Quelle: Eintrag [*Orthographische Konferenz von 1901*](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographische_Konferenz_von_1901) bei Wikipedia.